# Android Studio - Flutter Plugin - Moving method to another file by refactoring

Tags: android-studio, flutter, android-studio-3.0, automated-refactoring

Why I cannot (?) move a method from one Dart file to another using Android Studio and Flutter Plugin? My file is getting big and I decided to refactor it by separated some Widget build methods to their own files. I started by selecting one of the methods, performing the Android Studio's refactor command and click move as I always did with java. But looks like the only option is to move the actual Dart File to another Directory.

It would be nice if I could move the method and the entire tree to another file, and some others refactoring options.

Is there any way to facilitate this type of refactoring?

[image]

[image]

Android Studio 3.3 RC 2
Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5160847, built on December 3, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.15.0-39-generic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a open feature request of the dart sdk. Unfortunately, for more than two years it did not find much attention. https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/30310

Comment: Refactoring a method from a destination file to a source file should be a fundamental refactor in any IDE in my opinion. This is disappointing, cutting and pasting code is error prone and has no place in a modern IDE.

Comment: This is available on the Visual Studio plugin, when experimental refactorings are enabled.  It seems to work as expected, and I have done a lot of refactorings on VS Code. I still prefer IDEA for development, but this specific feature is still not available for IDEA.